# How to keep certain properties on an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this object. If a property's value is **null** I'm removing that property. But I have some special properties that I want to keep **no matter what** (even if their values are null). So far my code works great, but I don't like the fact that I have to use the OR **||** operator over and over.
Example:

> key === 'alwaysCountWithMe' || key === 'ABC' || key ==='doNotDeleteMe'
>   || key === 'specialProperty'

Here's my code:

```js
var object = {
  "firstname": null,
  "lastname": "White",
  "ABC": null,
  "hobby": null,
  "c": 3,
  "alwaysCountWithMe": null,
  "doNotDeleteMe": null,
  "specialProperty": null,
};

console.log(_.pickBy(object, (value, key) => !!value || key === 'alwaysCountWithMe' || key === 'ABC' || key === 'doNotDeleteMe' || key === 'specialProperty'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this without having to use the **||** over and over?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of keys to always keep, and check to see if it `includes(key)`:

```js
var object = {
  "firstname": null,
  "lastname": "White",
  "ABC": null,
  "hobby": null,
  "c": 3,
  "alwaysCountWithMe": null,
  "doNotDeleteMe": null,
  "specialProperty": null,
};
const alwaysKeep = ['alwaysCountWithMe', 'ABC', 'doNotDeleteMe', 'specialProperty'];

console.log(_.pickBy(object, (value, key) => !!value || alwaysKeep.includes(key)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use an array and `includes`:

```js
var object = {
  "firstname": null,
  "lastname": "White",
  "ABC": null,
  "hobby": null,
  "c": 3,
  "alwaysCountWithMe": null,
  "doNotDeleteMe": null,
  "specialProperty": null,
};

console.log(_.pickBy(object, (value, key) => !!value || ['alwaysCountWithMe', 'ABC', 'doNotDeleteMe', 'specialProperty'].includes(key)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I will keep `alwaysKeep` as an `Object` and than i need not to loop through it every time as JS object uses hashes so i can access with `O(1)` time complexity

```js
var object = {"firstname": null,"lastname": "White","ABC": null,"hobby": null,"c": 3,"alwaysCountWithMe": null,"doNotDeleteMe": null,"specialProperty": null,};

const alwaysKeep = {'alwaysCountWithMe': true, 'ABC': true, 'doNotDeleteMe': true, 'specialProperty':true};

console.log(_.pickBy(object, (value, key) => !!value || alwaysKeep[key]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to keep your keys on a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var object = {
  "firstname": null,
  "lastname": "White",
  "ABC": null,
  "hobby": null,
  "c": 3,
  "alwaysCountWithMe": null,
  "doNotDeleteMe": null,
  "specialProperty": null,
};

const keysSet = new Set(['alwaysCountWithMe', 'ABC', 'doNotDeleteMe', 'specialProperty']);

console.log(_.pickBy(object, (value, key) => !!value || keysSet.has(key)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```